# Can not delete faces/verts

Tags: mesh, uv, uv-image-editor

Now I need to first say that I am beyond a noob with Blender, so it's entirely likely I'm making an obvious error, but when I was preparing to get into UV mapping, I noticed a few issues that need to be deleted on multiple of my objects (really not sure where the issues came from. Must have changed something). All of them seem to be having this issue. I moved to delete it in every way I possibly could, but every time I did, nothing would happen. I tried to extrude it and try again, which only deleted the extruded parts.

[image: The view]
within UV editing
[image]

[image]

Also, I happen to be having an issue in the unwrapping process. After marking a seam and unwrapping, I'm getting a result that doesn't make much sense for what I'm unwrapping. Any guidance on this would be of value! I'm really not what what I'm doing wrong.

[image: UV MAPPING]

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking in the first part of your post.  Can you add another picture of the problem area?

Comment: Photos added. For context, I had copied the faces of a cylinder and then extruded the bottom portion to create the bottom of a handgrip. The top face stayed by accident and I then copied said object to make the pommel. Unfortunately the same mistake carried over and now I can't remove it.